# Wordpress BackWPup and Google Cloud Storage

Tags: wordpress, plugins, google-cloud-storage

I’ve installed the BackWPup plugin for my WordPress website and hooked it up to my Google Cloud Storage account. I have a problem that a full backup (70 MB zip file) doesn’t show up at my Google folder, but a smaller test backup (13 MB zip file) did show up. The plugin reports a successful transfer in both cases.  Does anyone know what the problem might be for the larger file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused because of a problem with the way that BackWPup sends large files to GWS using multi-part HTTP requests.  The cutoff for using multi-part messages was 50MB, so I increased it to larger than my backup file and everything worked ok.  I reported the problem on the BackWPup support forum so hopefully it will be fixed in a future release.